# MatDatepickerFilter - Filter function can't access class variable

Tags: angular-material2, datefilter

A MatDatePicker with a filter defined as followed:

```xml
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

```typescript
export class DatepickerFilterExample {
  someDateToBlock: number = 3;
  myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    const day = d.getDay();
    // THIS FUNCTION CANNOT ACCESS THE VARIABLE 'someDateToBlock'
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  }
}
```

I would like to access the variable someDateToBlock (or any other) in the filter function. Is there a workaround to make this possbile?

Comment: did u tried this.someDateToBlock ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is working, here is plunkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/oRGfxLSrn6GdfRhYO1rr?p=preview

```typescript
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {
  someDateToBlock: number = 3;
  myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    const day = d.getDay();
    // THIS FUNCTION CANNOT ACCESS THE VARIABLE 'someDateToBlock'
    return this.someDateToBlock;
  }
}
```

I checked with alert(this.someDateToBlock) also

Comment: Hmmmn .. I should have tried this definition of a filter function earlier.
My definition of the filter was originally 'dateFilter(d: date) {'
In that case the access to 'this.' is not working ...
In my presented code it is ... sorry for the inconsistencies

Comment: i prefer this solution instead of .bind(this), as this would not trigger change detection like .bind(this) does every second. thanks.

Answer (score 32):

I had the same issue, seems like material date picker doesn't have access to "this" of the component for filter function. For me changing:

```
[matDatepickerFilter]="myFilterFunction"
```

to

```
[matDatepickerFilter]="myFilterFunction.bind(this)"
```

did the trick.

Comment: it does ... =)
+1

Comment: Works for me, thanks! Why does that happens? Shouldn't it work like (change) method?

Comment: Binding to this in the view causes issues with change detection and prevents any dates in the calendar from being clickable. The filter function should be bound to this ahead of time. See https://github.com/angular/components/issues/21929

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
myLegalDate = (d: Date): boolean => {
    //Your code
    //You can see the variable someDateToBlock
    console.log(this.someDateToBlock);
}

myFilter = this.myLegalDate.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Type '(d: Date) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'DateFilterFn<Date | null>'

```
myFilter = (d: Date ** |null **): boolean => {
   const day = (d || new Date()).getDay();
   // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
   return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
};
```